# How do I count Hamiltonian paths of grid?

Tags: logical-deduction, calculation-puzzle, checkerboard

Let's say there is a 5x5 grid with a starting position in the upper left corner, and an ending position is lower left corner. How do I count how many Hamiltonian paths there are through the grid?

I know the answer is 86 for a 5x5 grid. But how should I calculate this? (4x4 is 8, 3x3 is 2) I want to learn calculate larger grids.

Comment: The same topic exists on Math.SE as well as SO.  There is no easy way to calculate Hamiltonian Paths.  I seem to remember the complexity being O(n^2*2^n) for finding whether or not a Hamiltonian path exists at all.

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/a/36378/58988

Comment: apparently there are 208, not 86

Comment: No there are 86.  The example you linked is travelling from bottom left to top right (diagonally opposed).  Tlaxin's post travels from top left to bottom left.

Comment: I also count 86.

Answer (score 6):

The [Hamiltonian path problem](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path_problem) is NP-complete.

This means there's no reasonable way for you to find *all* of these paths yourself on a sufficiently large grid. You might be able to find a few of them manually, but you will have no way of knowing if you've found all of them, even if you have. Counting them with certainty takes an unreasonable amount of computational time - we know of no faster way.

Comment: This is true for the general case.  But it is not necessarily true in a special case such as the square grid or a plane graph.

Comment: True, Florian. My intuition says there's no closed-form formula, because a natural divide-and-conquer approach splits the problem up into many count-P complete problems. BTW, the sequence http://oeis.org/A000532/list lists the currently known values.